# Posting rich media content onto users wall

Tags: facebook, flash

Does anyone know if there are changes in posting richmedia content(e.g: flash) to user wall?

I try published a post to my own wall but when I click on the image with a play icon, it open up a new window showing that flash instead of opening it within that post like a youtube video will do.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this too. It has to do with the fact that the browsing modes are different.

For example, if your Flash attachment is posted with a source protocol of https: , and the person viewing it is not browsing in secure mode, then they will not see any player.

If you post with http: and the person viewing is in secure mode, they will have the problem you explain.  A new window will pop.

For it to work perfect, their browsing mode should match how the source was posted.

I have not figured out how to handle this. But I have confirmed it.

Please let me know if you figure it out.